# UPDATED submitting a PHP form specific to this code using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

UPDATED: 
I'm putting together a website. One of the pages calls for me to submit a form to the server using mysql (through xampp, phpmyadmin). Unfortunately, I keep getting the following notice error:

Undefined index: PetType in C:\xampp\htdocs\pet-shop\includes\CustomerForm.php on line 34

when I try to submit the form any way, it tells gives the following message:

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15

there's a lot of code here so please let me know what would be a good place to post this. Thanks.

Here's the UPDATED code for the actual webpage (GroomingServices.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="PSStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Grooming</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<?php include 'header1.php';?>
</div>




<div id="ripmain">
<div id="menuet">

<nav>
<ul id="menubar">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="AboutUs.php">About</a></li>
<li><a href="Location.php">Location</a></li>
<li><a href="GroomingServices.php">Grooming</a></li>
<li><a href="ContactUs.php">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>

</div>

<div id="main">
<div id="menu">
<h2>Specials</h2>

<p>Check out our specials for this month:</p>

<navside>
<ul id="menubar2">
<li>$20 of baths Dogs and Cats</li>
<li>Teeth brushing 50% off with bath</li>
<li>Paw-di-cure $10</li>
</ul>
</navside>
<br />
<h2>Regular Perks</h2>
<p>
Teeth care: $10<br />
Baths: <br /> <li>0-10 lbs = $5; </li> 
<li>10-20 lbs = $10;</li>
<li>20-30 lbs = $15; </li>
<li>30-50 lbs = $20; </li>
<li>Over 50 lbs = $30 and up; </li> 
De-shedding: ask<br />
Nail trimming: $5<br />
Massage: $5-$10<br />
</p>

</div>

<div id="content">
<h1>Make your pet reservations here.</h1>
<p>The Pet Perks we offer:</p>

<form method="post" action="InsertEmployee.php">

<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>First name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="FirstName" size="40" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="LastName" size="40" required></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Address" size="40" required></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>City:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="City" size="40" required></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>State:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="State" size="40" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Zip:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Zip" size="40" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone Number:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" size="40" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="44">Email:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Email" value="" size="25" maxlength="40"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<label for="typeofPet">Type of Pet:</label>
<select name="typeofPet" id="typeofPet" required>
<option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
<optgroup label="Cat">
<option value="Cat">Cat</option>
<optgroup label="Dog">
<option value="Lab">Lab</option>
<option value="Chow">Chow</option>
<option value="Terrier">Terrier</option>
<option value="Bulldog">Bulldog</option>
<option value="Cocker Spaniel">Cocker Spaniel</option>
<option value="Great Dane">Great Dane</option>
<option value="Alaskan Huskey">Alaskan Huskey</option>
</optgroup>
</optgroup>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pet Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="PetName" value="" size="25" maxlength="40" required></td>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td>Neutered or Spayed:</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="neutered" id="neutered"> <label for="neutered">Neutered</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="spayed" id="spayed"> <label for="spayed">Spayed</label>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pet Age:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="PetAge" id="petage" value="" size="25" maxlength="40"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" height="20">
<input type="hidden" name="discount" id="discount" value="20%">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
</form>

<div class="clearer"></div>
</div>

<?php include 'footer1.php';?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the UPDATED action file (InsertEmployee.php):

```
<?php
$dbEntries = $_POST;
foreach ($dbEntries as &$entry)
{
    $entry = dbString($entry);
}

@$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','pyth0n1','pet_shop');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Cannot connect to database: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query = "INSERT INTO grooming
(FirstName, LastName, Title, Address, City, State, Zip, PhoneNumber, Email, PetType, Breed, PetName, NeuteredOrSpayed, PetAge)
    VALUES ('" .    $dbEntries['FirstName'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['LastName'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['Address'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['City'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['State'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['Zip'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['PhoneNumber'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['Email'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['PetType'] . "-" .
$dbEntries['Breed'] . "-" .
$dbEntries['PetName'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['NeuteredOrSpayed'] . "-" .
$dbEntries['Spayed'] . "-" .
$dbEntries['Neutered'] . "-" .
$dbEntries['PetAge'] . "')";

if ($db->query($query))
{
echo '<div align="center">Customer Added</div>
<a href="CustomerReport.php">Customer Report</a>';
$showForm = false;
}
else
{
echo '<div align="center">Insert failed</div>';
}
?>
```

here's the insertemployee file for your review as well:

```
<?php
$dbEntries = $_POST;
foreach ($dbEntries as &$entry)
{
$entry = dbString($entry);
}

@$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','pyth0n1','pet_shop');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo 'Cannot connect to database: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query = "INSERT INTO grooming
(FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, Zip, PhoneNumber, Email, PetType, PetName, NeuteredOrSpayed, PetAge)
VALUES ('" .    $dbEntries['FirstName'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['LastName'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['Address'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['City'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['State'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['Zip'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['PhoneNumber'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['Email'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['PetType'] . "-" .
$dbEntries['PetName'] . "','" .
$dbEntries['NeuteredOrSpayed'] . "-" .
$dbEntries['Spayed'] . "-" .
$dbEntries['Neutered'] . "-" .
$dbEntries['PetAge'] . "')";

if ($db->query($query))
{
echo '<div align="center">Customer Added</div>
<a href="CustomerReport.php">Customer Report</a>';
$showForm = false;
}
else
{
echo '<div align="center">Insert failed</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: you're using MSSQL / Oracle syntax for your values `[value-x]`, that isn't MySQL syntax. Plus, you're also not executing `$sql...` in GroomingServices.php so that too is *"failing miserably"*, but not checking for it.

Comment: then you're using `mysql_` in one and `mysqli_` in the other.

Comment: oh ... let me take a look at that ...

Comment: i'm new to this; so please forgive my questions and mistakes; went in and made some changes to both of the files listed above. will post the new code shortly for your review; thanks for your help

Comment: It's complaining that `$_POST['PetType']` doesn't exist, because you named it `typeofPet`. They're also case sensitive. `$_POST['Spayed']` is not the same as `$_POST['spayed']`. Keep your upper and lower case in check and make sure they're the same. `die('<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>');` would help you figuring out what `InsertEmployee` is actually receiving.

Comment: ok; and where would I post this? die('<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>');

Comment: @greatscott If you want to see the contents of `$_POST` you have to put this line in the start of the file where you're expecting the `$_POST` values - that means the `InsertEmployee.php` file.

Comment: Okay; i give up; tried everything. would it be easier for someone to just review my code?

Answer (score 0):

You miss the passing value of `Title` field in value.

Comment: yes, i caught that; but i deleted title bc it doesn't exist in my table or any of my files; would you like to see all of my code? because this page requires like 7 or 8 sep (but short) files

Comment: Where you have stored InsertEmployee.php?

Comment: it's in my includes folder; and i went in and fixed that error; but i'll post that for you so you double check it; so that's been posted above;

Comment: now the only error that I still have is the following: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15  ...... and it won't recognize my processcustomer file